# Shell Script: Length space separated

Tags: linux, shell

How can I make the code below to return the number of words separated by space?

```
example='aaa bbb ccc ddd eee'
echo ${#example}
```

The command `echo ${#example}` returns total number of letters (19). What's the best command to returns total number of words (5)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ foo=($example)

$ echo ${#foo[*]}
5
```

If you want to do it without a variable

```
$ set $example

$ echo $#
5
```

Comment: `[@]` <- what does it mean? where can I read more about that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `wc` command which stands for `word count`

```
wc -w <<< "$example"

wc -w <<< "asdf asdf asdf"
```

Comment: Even better because without filename.